# How to fix the following issue with razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following code in Razor, why doesn't it work?
All I want to do is check to see if data has a value, if it does then print it with to 2 decimal places and append a % sign..

```
<td> 
    @if (data.HasValue == true)
    {

        @string.Format("{0:F2}", data)%

    }
</td>
```

it says I don't need am @ at the start of the string.  I take that off, then it complain about an ;

but I got it to work by doing the following

```
@if (data.HasValue == true)
{
    <td>           
        @string.Format("{0:F2}", data)%
    </td>
}
else
{
    <td>

   </td>

}
```

How can I fix the first set of code to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor has no clue what you want to do with the string.Format call.

To fix that, use:

```
<td> 
    @if (data.HasValue == true)
    {

        @:@string.Format("{0:F2}", data)%

    }
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this its working ..

```
<td> 
    @if (data.HasValue == true)
    {

      string.Format("{0:F2} {1}", data, "%");

    }
</td>
```

Or you can try this

```
<td> 
        @if (data.HasValue == true)
        {

          @:@String.Format("{0:F2}", data)%;

        }
    </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is guaranteed to work, give it a try:

```
<td> 
    @{
       if (data.HasValue)// you don't need to compare to true because it's already a boolean :)
       {    
            string.Format("{0:F2}", data)%    
       }
     }
</td>
```